# Sandbox Red function

Tags: rebol, red

I'm planning to write an application for managing a game-server in [Red](http://www.red-lang.org/). It should be extendable by using interpreted Red scripts. Now, I want to set restrictions for this scripts (I want to "sandbox" them) and remove specific functionality like I/O, and some other functions.

I know that in Rebol such things are archived using `secure`, but is something similar possible in Red too? I've already done some experiments with `context`s, but I just don't get it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Red is probably not at the point the will satisfy your needs yet. `secure` will be added in future versions, but right now you can change everything, if you really want to. Remember, it is still alpha version.

You can take a look at [this article](http://red.qyz.cz/safe-and-persistent-locals.html) that describes some ways to make changing stuff harder (but not impossible) in the meantime.

Comment: Hm... than I probably have to write it in Rebol... Well, thank you for your answer and the helpful link.